# How to prevent external drops on fullcalendar before today, and when eventConstraint is already referencing businesshours

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have my business hours being define dynamically per location that prevent the dropping of externals, but I would also like to prevent external drops from being possible if the date/time is before today.  Here is some of my existing code:

```
        drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) {

            if (date >= moment().startOf('day')) {

                var contactResURL = 'https://url.com';

                window.location.replace(contactResURL);

            } 
        },
        eventConstraint: 'businessHours',
        businessHours: bhours,
        events: data,
    });
```

The code that I presented doesn't show all of the actions that happen, but should illustrate how I can prevent information from being saved.  That being said, it still drops the event onto the calendar.  I would like to prevent it from dropping on the calendar before today, and also to be able to create a dynamic time that prevents reservations from being created within a number of days from today.

My question is: Is it possible to either have multiple eventConstraints (not selectConstraints), or can businesshours somehow include times before today, and not be possible after a number of days from now?

Comment: firstly, for more reliable date comparisons, I'd use moment's query functions: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/ e.g. isSame, isBefore, isAfter etc. Secondly your "pageRedirect()" function is completely redundant. You define it then immediately execute it. Why not just execute the code directly?

Comment: Thank you for the momentjs info.  To answer the pageRedirect... I added some of the different aspects of my code, and removed a great deal, so it is redundant in this example.  That being said, do you have any insight on how to prevent the actual drop?

Comment: I suspect if you return false from the function when your conditions aren't  it might stop it. I haven't got time to try it right now